# Unable to setup Laravel 9 Bootstrap 5 auth

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

I am battling to get Laravel 9 and bootstrap 5 auth working.

Windows 10
php  v8.1.6
node v18.12.1
npm  v9.1.3

1. composer create-project laravel/laravel test
2. composer require laravel/ui
3. php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
4. npm install
5. npm run dev

I get the following error when running step 5:

> failed to load config from
> C:\Dropbox#Work#Development\www\test\vite.config.js error when
> starting dev server: Error: cannot test case insensitive FS,
> CLIENT_ENTRY does not point to an existing file:
> C:\dist\client\client.mjs
> at testCaseInsensitiveFS (C:\Dropbox#Work#Development\www\test\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs:3432:15)
> at Object. (C:\Dropbox#Work#Development\www\test\node_modules\vite\dist\node-cjs\publicUtils.cjs:3437:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
> at _require.extensions. [as .js] (file:///C:/Dropbox/%23Work/%23Development/www/test/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:62854:17)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
> at Object. (C:\Dropbox#Work#Development\www\test\node_modules\vite\index.cjs:7:31)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to change directory to the root folder of your project then proceed from step 2. Then is should just be fine.

1. composer create-project laravel/laravel test
2. cd test
3. composer require laravel/ui
4. php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
5. npm install
6. npm run dev
   (You can stop the run when you see message 'APP_URL: http://localhost' from the terminal)
7. npm run build
   (You can stop the run when you see message 'built in ***s' from the terminal)

You might require to add jquery.js and popper.js(aka @popperjs/core) into the projects root_dir/resources/js  folder. You can also add bootstrap.min.js into root_dir/resources/css before running step 5 to 7. If you forgot there is no harm of adding them and repeating step 5 to 7. Finally run your project.

8. php artisan serve --port=8080
   Or pick your preferred port.